# How to restore default iPod playlists on Amarok?

Tags: linux, ipod, kubuntu, playlists, amarok

I wanted to "reset" the collection on my iPod and ended up accidentally deleting, through Amarok, all the playlists, including the default ones like "Most Played" and "Highest Rated". Since these are dynamic playlists with a special meaning for iPod, I don't think creating new, normal playlists with the same name will bring their special behavior back.

---

How do I restore them with the same dynamic functionality? Is there a way to do that on Amarok? Rhythmbox? GTKPod? Command line?

P.S.: not entirely sure what the policy about iPod questions are, but this one in particular seems to me to be very computer-related because, although it's about interfacing with a device, everything has to be done on my computer, using standard PC libraries/programs, etc. If it's still off-topic, please point me to where I could post it.

Comment: You can go ahead and remove the PS part: SU does not cover "electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer."  Your question is therefore entirely on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can re-create some of those playlist by creating a *smart playlist* in iTunes.  Go to File > New Smart Playlist, then set your parameters, sorry if this does not help.